# How can I specify some days to be available for reservation swiftui or UIKit

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

How can I specify some days to be available for reservation in :  swiftui , UIKit  or if have any way in Firebase

this is Example:

day : 16,17,18,20 is available in

[image: calendar example]

```
struct Test4: View {

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()
let dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd, MMMM, yyyy"
    return formatter
}()
@State private var reservationDate = Date()

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        DatePicker("", selection: $reservationDate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date)
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
        Spacer()
        Text("\(reservationDate, formatter: dateFormatter2)")
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
        Spacer()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to implement it and can you show us your code for it? If so, please edit your question and add the code so we can help you easier

Comment: No, because i am not know how do it